# Connect Mail.app to Exchange Server 2003 OWA?

Tags: macos, exchange, apple-mail

I have been able to connect various Android devices to MS Exchange Server 2003.  Usually I put in the server address: `mail.mydomain.com`

I put in my email address, username, password and it just works.

I do not believe it is using POP or SMTP, it must be connecting through OWA or .. ?

When I put in the server address to Apple Mail (OS X 10.6.7) it fails to connect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Exchange as account type?

Comment: yes.    As I understand it, the issue is that Mail and even the latest Office for Mac will work with Exchange Server 2007, but 2003 is difficult or not possible.  I tried all sorts of things and could never get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did finally come up with a work-around - I used [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net).  Basically you install it, type in the server address and other information and I set it up as imap in mail.   It seems to work fine and has been working fine now for a couple weeks.  DavMail has to be running of course.